# How to use Pagination when calling Azure REST API

Tags: rest, azure, pagination, azure-logic-apps

I'm just using a simple logic app to call the whole list of Azure VMs, however only the first 50 are returned, along with a NextLink pagination. I'm not too sure how to call the rest of the results.

I've been looking at the MS page, but I'm still unsure what needs to be done: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall#virtualmachinelistresult

Can this be done via a header in the HTTP request?

[image]

Paginated results:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, the value of the `nextLink` is a URL. You will use this URL only for fetching the next set of results.

Comment: To expand on this answer, if you wanted to exhaustively fetch all the records, you would keep following the nextLink property until it is no longer returned (which indicates that there are no more records available)

Comment: @SzymonWylezol, that's what I was thinking, but how do you do that for this type of request. How am I able to call nextLink via a HTTP Get method until there are no more nextLink

Comment: @Beefcake you can use an until loop with @equals(actionBody('getResources')?['nextLink'], null) as condition

Comment: I would love to test this, but sadly my client has just put in place some API management restrictions from outside their tenant. Looks like it'll have to wait a bit....   Thanks @SzymonWylezol